# Azure SDK - Conflict DLLs

Tags: azure

I am using this APIs from Nuget at the same project:

Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager.Fluent
Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MediaServices.Client

I can upload videos and create ResourceGroups, for example. But not at the same project because this error:

No se puede cargar el archivo o ensamblado 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory, Version=2.28.3.860, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' ni una de sus dependencias. La definición del manifiesto del ensamblado no coincide con la referencia al ensamblado. (Excepción de HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Is it possible to use both DLLs in the same project?

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to use both DLLs in the same project?

If your project is using the .NETFramework 4.5.2, it **is not possible** to use both DLLs in the same project. If your project is using NETFramework 4.6.1+ then it is possible.

We could get the more information about [Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager.Fluent](http://Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager.Fluen) and 
[Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MediaServices.Client](https://www.nuget.org/packages/windowsazure.mediaservices) from nuget.

We could know that one of the dependencies of [Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager.Fluent](http://Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager.Fluen) is that 
[Microsoft.Rest.ClientRuntime.Azure.Authentication (>= 2.3.2)](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Rest.ClientRuntime.Azure.Authentication/)

And one of dependencies of Microsoft.Rest.ClientRuntime.Azure.Authentication (>= 2.3.2)  in the .NETFramework 4.5.2  is that **Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory (= 2.28.3)**

[image]

But the dependencies of Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MediaServices.Client is **Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory (>= 3.13.1)**

[image]

**In summary**: **there are conflict if using them in the .NETFramework 4.5.2.
If .net 4.6.1+ framework is possible, please use them in that .netframework.**